refreshing current tab in lwc

I am trying to get the current console tab (tab with case number 060833...) to get refreshed when I press the Remove menu item, but only the feed section is getting refreshed...
    import { IsConsoleNavigation, getFocusedTabInfo, refreshTab } from 'lightning/platformWorkspaceApi';
    ...
    
 async refreshTabHandler() {
    let focusedTab = await getFocusedTabInfo();
    refreshTab(focusedTab.tabId);
  }

    removeFromCase(event){
        console.log('event.target.value'+event.target);
        unlinkOrderData({
          orderNumber: null,
          orderId: null,
          brand: event.target.value.brand__c,
          caseId : this.recordId
        }).then((result) => {
          console.log('result' + JSON.stringify(result));
          this.showToast('Success!!', 'Order unlinked from case Succesfully!', 'success', 'dismissable');        
          this.refreshTabHandler();
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
          this.showToastOnError(error.body.message);
        });
      }


These lines of code in your function looks like its doing it already
getFocusedTabInfo().then((tabInfo) => {refreshTab(tabInfo.tabId);})

Included an image and updated the issue starting paragraph above.

I tried it with promise too. getting the console error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: getFocusedTabInfo() - Failed to get tabInfo for focused tab.

I am getting Tab Info: {"tabId":"ctab0","url":"https://gg--gg.sandbox.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Case/gg/view","pinned":false,"closeable":true,"title":"06083329 | Case","icon":"standard:case","iconAlt":"Case","highlighted":false,"pageReference":{"type":"standard__recordPage","attributes":{"objectApiName":"Case","recordId":"5001x00000AgdIdAAJ","actionName":"view"},"state":{}},"isSubtab":false,"parentTabId":null,"subtabs":[],"focused":true,"recordId":"5001x0000gA9dIdAAJ"}

You can use notifyRecordUpdateAvailable
Quoted from the document:

Informs Lightning Data Service that record data has changed so that Lightning Data Service can take the appropriate actions to keep wire adapters updated with the latest record data. Call this function to notify Lightning Data Service that a record has changed outside its mechanisms

you can include this in your .then block:
.then((result) => {
      console.log('result' + JSON.stringify(result));
      notifyRecordUpdateAvailable([{recordId: this.recordId}]); //wrap the next showToast line to perform once this promise is resolved.
      this.showToast('Success!!', 'Order unlinked from case Succesfully!', 'success', 'dismissable');        

*code credit to original author and documentation linked above.
Personally, I prefer using async/await.
